# how can i plot a route map?

Tags: javascript, google-maps, plot

I am writing a simple application to plot multiple marker in the google map and  connect it  thought a path as it looks like a route .
 I can plot multiple marker . and search some article which plot the route map . but i can not plot it . i  wrote in javascript

```
<html> 
<head>
<title>Google Maps Multiple Markers</title>
<script src="http://maps.google.com/maps/api/js?sensor=false"   type="text/javascript"></script>
</head>
<body>
<div id="map" style="height: 1000px; width: 800px;">
</div>
<script type="text/javascript">
var markers= [
 {
 "lat": '13.03563',
 "lng": '77.51283',
  "description": '1'
  },
  {
  "lat": '13.04501',      
   "lng": '77.55674',
   "description": '2'
 },
 {
  "lat": '13.03747',
  "lng": '77.5629',
  "description": '3'
 ];
  var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map'), {
  zoom: 10,
 center: new google.maps.LatLng(markers[0].lat, markers[0].lng),
  mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
});
var infowindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow();
var marker, i;
for (i = 0; i < markers.length; i++) { 
marker = new google.maps.Marker({
position: new google.maps.LatLng(markers[i].lat , markers[i].lng),
  map: map
});
}
</script>
</body>
</html>
     }
   ];
```

how can i draw the route ? any suggestion

Comment: There are syntax errors in the posted code, `Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token ]`,  Please post a [Minimal, Complete, Tested and Readable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) that demonstrates your issue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code works for me, just fixed some `}` and `]`.

http://jsfiddle.net/3qo8kg2o/

But I think you should use [polyline](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/examples/polyline-simple) instead.

Answer (score 0):

Seem you are searching for google maps direction service

look ad this [Direction documentation](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/directions/)

and at this [direction samples](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/examples/directions-simple)

If is not the direction servici what you are looking for but you want to connect the marker with a line. draw a LineString between every markers coordinate.

Comment: If you find my answer useful please rate it